# Modify existing table style

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

This question is probably dumb and silly, but I really haven't found any information in manual and on the internet.

Since LibreOffice 5.3, there were introduced so-called table styles. I understand how to create and apply them, but I don't understand how to modify existing one.

Is it possible? How?

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you have 5.3.1 or newer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LibreOffice 5.3.0 showed the option to modify as well as delete.  However this has not yet been implemented and resulted in [a crash](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101648).

So in 5.3.1, the ability to modify was taken out completely.  The newest version 5.4.0 does not have modifying either.

For the time being, the only options are to Add, Delete or Rename, as described in the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/index.php?title=Writer/AutoFormat_for_Tables&Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=5.3#bm_id3148770).

It is also possible to unzip the ODT file and edit styles.xml with a text editor, although each table style has multiple "table-cell" items, making this approach rather cumbersome.

Comment: still true with 6.1.2.1

Comment: And with 7.0.3.1

Comment: And with 7.4.0 sadly