# How to format only the odd (or even) rows in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to create a table like the one in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPbDk.png) in LibreOffice.

Is it possible in LibreOffice?

Comment: Mark your cells and use: Format -> Autoformat Styles... look at the patterns section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the table, right-click. Select Style, then choose one of the "Box List" style.

[image]

**Edit (to follow up on the question from the comment):**

To change rows color requires a bit of patience as you will have to do it row by row. Select Table Properties, go to the Background tab, select Row from the dropdown list. Click on the color button, select your color.

You can't create a custom styles as answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1238706/855367) (See the comment stating that it is still true for version 6).

Comment: Can I set custom background color for the odd rows?

Comment: @Max See edit to the answer.